# ASP.NET MVC 2 Custom view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewengine

Im developing a custom view engine for implementing themes for my asp.net mvc 2 web app. The problem that I am facing is that in this function:

```
public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
```

The parameter "masterName" is always empty, although the viewName is not empty and that view has a master page associated to it.

I would like to know the master page, so I can have a default theme and allow to create a theme that only changes the masterpages but not the content pages. So when a theme is selected, I want to use the masterpage of the theme but the content page of the default theme. But also I want to give the ability to create themes that override the master page and some content pages, and some other not. For this I would only need the masterName that the page is using, but I receive an empty string :(

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!
Juan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter "masterName" is optional.  By default a view will use the master page defined in the View, but if the paraeter is specified it will override this with the mast page supplied.

eg:

```
Return View("viewname", Model); // uses default master page
Return View("viewname", Model, "MasterName"); // users supplied MasterName
```

Therefore one solution is to leave the master name value blank, unless overriden by a selected theme, and only then to override it in the View call.  This doesn't need a custom view engine

Comment: As I want to change also some pages depending on the them I need a custom view engine. Is there any way that I can get the masterpage name that is defined in the View?

Comment: Its not something that is made available, unless you dig very deep into the WebFormViewEngine within the Render methods.  Unless it's overridden its not generally needed.